# How to display selected option from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Task:**

Create a dropdown list with options for user to select. When user select an option from the dropdown list. An additional field will automatically appear to display the option selected by the user.

**What has been done:**
The dropdown list has already been created and it is showing the list of options for user to select. I have also managed to display the option selected by hardcoding in the option selected as part of a conditional statement.

**Issue:**
How am I able to allow the conditional statement to read from the dropdown list selected instead of me hardcoding in the value.

**Code:**

DropDown code:

```
  <li class="bigfield">
                    <select name ="Agency" id="AgencyDetails" onchange = "return val(this.value);">
                    <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Agency..</option>
                    <option value ="Name 1"> Name1</option>
                    <option value ="Name 2"> Name2</option>
                    <option value ="Name 3"> Name3</option>
                    <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
            </li>
```

Conditional Statement to see which option has been selected:

```
<script>
function val(x) {
    document.getElementById("AddDiv").style.display = x == "Others" ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("Name1").style.display = x == "Name 1" ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("Name2").style.display = x == "Name 2" ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("Name3").style.display = x == "Name 3" ? "block" : "none";
}
</script>
```

Hardcoded View of selected option:

```
<div  id = "Name1" style ="display:none">
            <li class ="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agent1" type="text" name="agentName" id="agentName" <?php echo 'value="Agency 1"'?> disabled="disabled"/></li>
            </div>
.....(identical for Name2 and Name3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery, this is about as easy as it gets.

```js
$('#AgencyDetails').on('change',function(){
    $('#result').html($(this).val());   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name ="Agency" id="AgencyDetails">
   <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Agency..</option>
   <option value ="Name 1"> Name1</option>
   <option value ="Name 2"> Name2</option>
   <option value ="Name 3"> Name3</option>
   <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
 </select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The above code would be put inside a [`$(document).ready(..)`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) like so:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       // above code here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, May I ask where do I put that following code into?

Comment: Answer updated, but read the linked documentation (and spend some time on the jQuery documentation in general - it'll help)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation.have understood

Comment: would like to ask you if it is also possible for me to use `var selectBox = form.fieldname;
var selectedText = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text`

Answer (score 1):

For code simplicity try modifying your HTML and make `<option>` value equal to `id` of `<div>` which you want to make visible.

```js
$("div.result").hide();
$("select#AgencyDetails").change(function(){
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  $("div.result").hide();
  $("div#"+selectedVal).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="bigfield">
  <select name ="Agency" id="AgencyDetails" ">
     <option value ="0" selected = "selected">Select Agency..</option>
     <option value ="Agency1"> Name1</option>
     <option value ="Agency2"> Name2</option>
     <option value ="Agency3"> Name3</option>
     <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
  </select>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="result" id = "Agency1" style ="display:none;">
     <li class ="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agent1" type="text" name="agentName" id="agentName" disabled="disabled"/></li>
</div>
                                                                                   
<div  class="result" id = "Agency2" style ="display:none;">
     <li class ="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agent2" type="text" name="agentName" id="agentName" disabled="disabled"/></li>                                                         </div>
                                                                                   <div  class="result" id = "Agency3" style ="display:none;">
     <li class ="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agent3" type="text" name="agentName" id="agentName" disabled="disabled"/></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery `eq()` and `selectedIndex`:

```js
var details;
var agencyChanged = function(e) {
  details.hide();
  var i = this.selectedIndex;
  if (0 === i) return;
  var toShow = details.eq(i)
  if (!toShow.length)
    toShow = details.eq(0);
  toShow.show();
};
$(function() {
  details = $('div.details');
  $('#AgencyDetails').on('change keyup', agencyChanged).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Agency" id="AgencyDetails">
  <option value="0">Select Agency..</option>
  <option value="Name 1">Name1</option>
  <option value="Name 2">Name2</option>
  <option value="Name 3">Name3</option>
  <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
<div id="AddDiv" class='details'>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input placeholder="AddDiv" type="text" name="agentName" />
  </li>
</div>
<div id="Name1" class='details'>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input placeholder="Name1" type="text" name="agentName" disabled="disabled" />
  </li>
</div>
<div id="Name2" class='details'>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input placeholder="Name2" type="text" name="agentName" disabled="disabled" />
  </li>
</div>
<div id="Name3" class='details'>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input placeholder="Name3" type="text" name="agentName" disabled="disabled" />
  </li>
</div>
```

With `data` attribute:

```js
var details;
var agencyChanged = function(e) {
  details.hide();
  var id = $(this).find(':selected').data('id');
  if (id) $('#' + id).show();
};
$(function() {
  details = $('div.details');
  $('#AgencyDetails').on('change keyup', agencyChanged).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Agency" id="AgencyDetails">
  <option value="0">Select Agency..</option>
  <option value="Name 1" data-id="Name1">Name1</option>
  <option value="Name 2" data-id="Name2">Name2</option>
  <option value="Name 3" data-id="Name3">Name3</option>
  <option value="Others" data-id="AddDiv">Others</option>
</select>
<div id="AddDiv" class='details'>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input placeholder="AddDiv" type="text" name="agentName" />
  </li>
</div>
<div id="Name1" class='details'>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input placeholder="Name1" type="text" name="agentName" disabled="disabled" />
  </li>
</div>
<div id="Name2" class='details'>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input placeholder="Name2" type="text" name="agentName" disabled="disabled" />
  </li>
</div>
<div id="Name3" class='details'>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input placeholder="Name3" type="text" name="agentName" disabled="disabled" />
  </li>
</div>
```